# Log into hidden administrator account with standard user

Tags: command-line, windows-vista, windows-registry

I created an administrator user account (jeff) and then downgraded an existing account (jen) to a standard user.  All was good I accomplished my goal except I didn't want the admin account to show on the login screen.  So I used regedit to edit the following key:

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\WindowsNT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\SpecialAccounts\UserList`

Everything was still fine until I tried to log in to the admin user and realized CTRL-ALT-DEL no longer shows the alternate login screen (Windows Vista).  Now I have a standard user account with no way to log into the admin account.  Can someone point me to a solution?

I did try using runas to use regedit as an admin:

`runas /user:jeff c:\windows\regedit.exe`

I also tried run cmd.exe as an admin

`runas /user:jeff c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe`

I lastly tried the following command both with and without using runas:

`net user jeff /active:yes`

Comment: What happened with your runas command?

Comment: have you tried using the password with the runas command?

Comment: You can follow the instruction [from here](http://www.wincert.net/tips/1617-unhide-hidden-administrator-account-on-windows-7.html). Involves booting from Win7 DVD and then using regedit.

Comment: Rik's comment should be an answer actually..

Comment: @Sweet72 The answer was so short and simple, so i thought it would be best as a comment. But now i added it as an answer (for future reference) citing the source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following instructions came from [this site](http://www.wincert.net/tips/1617-unhide-hidden-administrator-account-on-windows-7.html) and are duplicated here in case this site goes offline.

---

If you would like to unhide the hidden Administrator account on Windows 7 Operating System, here's how you can do it:

1. Boot Win 7 DVD, go to command prompt and type regedit -it, open registry editor
2. Click on HKLM hive and next navigate `File>>Load hive`. Navigate to `C:\Windows\System32\config` folder and choose `SOFTWARE` file load it and assign this hive any name for example REM_SOFTWARE
3. Open key:
   `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\REM_SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\SpecialAccounts\UserList`
   and remove this account or better way remove the whole key:
   `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\REM_SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\SpecialAccounts`